# is this possible $df(ax)/d(ax)=df(x)/d(x)$?

Tags: calculus

Once i saw a TA doing this, but it seems a little bit weird for me

$$
\frac{dF(KL)}{d(KL)}=\frac{L*dF(K)}{L*d(K)}=\frac{dF(K)}{d(K)}
$$

Is it possible to asume this for any homogeneous function of degree 1? Or is this due to the chain rule?

Thanks in advance )

Comment: Read comments to answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620333/homogeneous-function-has-its-derivative-homogeneous-of-one-less-degree

Comment: Is $L$ constant?

Comment: is $F$ linear function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little weird indeed ,You know what kind of notation it is ;BAD notation ,probably a short hand for researchers in a hurry . Lets see F is a function ,lets put y =F(x) (y is a function of X) .  Let x =KL  L a fixed nonzero constant throughout (x is a function of K ) . Let K be an unspecified real number ( the letter"K" is called of course a variable ).Composing we get y= F(LK)  so y is also a function of K (it's name is NOT F) .

The chain rule says dy/dK =dy/dx  * dx/dK =dy/dx*L We can write this loosely as

(1/L) d F(LK)/dK = d F(LK)/d(LK)  .Now is f is homogeneous then F(LK) =LF(K) and since d LF(K)/dK= LdF(K)/dK  the L and 1/L cancel  giving dF(K)/dK=dF(LK)/(LK) . 
   So yes you get the right answer for homogeneous functions .Guess the notation can be useful even if bad .Regards ,Stuart M.N.

Comment: I think you should use Latex in your answer to make it readable.

Comment: What is Latex ?

Comment: That was quite useful, I'm going to rewrite it just for the sake of it:
$\frac{dF(KL)}{d(K)}=\frac{dF(KL)}{d(KL)}\frac{dKL}{dK}=\frac{dF(KL)}{d(KL)}L \leftrightarrow \frac{dF(KL)}{d(K)} \frac{1}{L}=\frac{dF(KL)}{d(KL)}$
Since $y$ is an homogeneous function of degree "1": $F(KL)=LF(K)$. Thus:
$\frac{dF(KL)}{d(KL)}=\frac{dF(K)}{d(K)}$
Easy peasy lemon squeezy.